# How to understand exception condition usage in Python?

Tags: python

I came across a code that keeps asking the user for input until the user finally input an integer.

```
while True:
    try:
        n = input('Please enter an integer.')
        n = int(n)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('Input is not an integer. Try again.')
        
print('Correct input of an integer.')
```

I tried out the code by entering a string as input and it asks me to try again. I assume it gives me a ValueError when it is executing

```
n = int(n)
```

as it can not convert a string to integer. Which the code then jumps to execute the except condition. However, I don't understand why am I still in the while loop after executing the except condition? It doesn't return True or something to continue running the while loop?

Also I entered a float as my input and it again ask me to try again. I do not understand as wouldn't int(n) be able to convert my float input to an integer without any ValueError?

Comment: "It doesn't return True or something to continue running the while loop?" - you don't need to explicitly do anything to continue running a loop. Particularly, `return`ing something would immediately end the loop.

Comment: It's nothing related to the except part, you have created an infinite while loop by giving while True:, You can solve it by either changing infinite True condition or add a `break`statement when the exception happens

Comment: "Also I entered a float as my input" - no, you entered a bunch of characters that could be parsed as a float by `float`, but `input` doesn't do that parsing. Whatever you type, `input` returns a string. `int` only parses strings that look like integers.

Comment: If you just "fall off" the bottom of code in any of the try / except suites, execution continues at the first statement after the last suite (a "suite" is a set of code at the same indentation level). In the case of the except, the "next statement" is just the end of the `while` so it loops back to the start. In the case of the float, well it isn't an integer. You could do `int(float(n))` if you want to handle both. Since integers are floats too, that case works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a break statement after `print('Input is not an integer. Try again.')` or else it will keep looping back. As for handling floats, you could use `int(float(n))` as suggested by **tdelaney**.

```
while True:
    try:
        n = input('Please enter an integer.')
        n = int(float(n))
        print('Correct input of an integer.')
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('Input is not an integer. Try again.')
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `trace` module to see statement by statement execution of the code:

```
$ python -m trace -t test.py
 --- modulename: test, funcname: <module>
test.py(1): while True:
test.py(2):     try:
test.py(3):         n = input('Please enter an integer.')
Please enter an integer.notaninteger
test.py(4):         n = int(n)
test.py(6):     except ValueError:
test.py(7):         print('Input is not an integer. Try again.')
Input is not an integer. Try again.
test.py(2):     try:
test.py(3):         n = input('Please enter an integer.')
Please enter an integer.1.1
test.py(4):         n = int(n)
test.py(6):     except ValueError:
test.py(7):         print('Input is not an integer. Try again.')
Input is not an integer. Try again.
test.py(2):     try:
test.py(3):         n = input('Please enter an integer.')
Please enter an integer.3
test.py(4):         n = int(n)
test.py(5):         break
test.py(9): print('Correct input of an integer.')
Correct input of an integer.
```

In the first two test cases, the exception is run and you end up back at the top of the loop. In the final case, the break is hit which breaks you out of the nearest enclosing loop... the `while`.